# android adding or removing hour from timestamp in database

Tags: java, database, sqlite, datetime

I want to subtract a few days from my timestamp in Android.

I have an [SQLite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) database with a date field of the type long.
When I execute a query where I say `date = date - (3 * 86400000)` I sometimes experience a one hour difference as a result when converting it to a readable date.

But how is this possible? Has it to do with the daylight savings of one hour in my timezone?

Because I would find it strange if that's the reason because you are doing calculations with two long values and after converting them back to datetime there shouldn't be a daylight saving issue?

Comment: How do you know there's a one hour difference? Are you converting these to `Date` or a `Calendar` and checking? It would be helpful to see some example code to see what you're doing.

Comment: Timezone could be an issue if one is set while the other is not.  Since Java date defaults to GMT, that would be your basis in figuring out who's at what time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies but I found a solution.
It seems that when you add days in milliseconds to your timestamp and there is an hour difference in daylight settings in between, the date is automatically corrected.

When I do the following, the hour is ignored:

```
Date d = new Date();
d.setDays(d.getDays() - 2);
```

However, I would recommend using the Joda library because it's mush more flexible and easy to work with.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Use modern *java.time* classes.

If you meant 3 days as in calendar dates, do this:

```java
Instant                                // Represent a moment in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds.
.ofEpochSecond( x )                    // Parse some number of whole seconds or milliseconds from the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC.
.atZone(                               // Adjust from UTC to the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
    ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )    // Assign the time zone by which you want the context of their calendar for adding dates.
)                                      // Returns a `ZonedDateTime` object.
.plus(                                 // Move to another moment by adding a span-of-time.
    Period.ofDays( 3 )                 // Define a span of time as a number of days on the calendar (date) without regard for the length of a day.
)                                      // Returns another `ZonedDateTime` object.
.toInstant()                           // Adjust from a time zone to UTC. Same moment, different wall-clock time.
.toEpochSeconds()                      // or maybe `toEpochMillis` depending on your practice with your `long` number.
```

Write your SQL as:

```sql
SELECT * FROM event_ WHERE when_ >= ? ;  -- Find events occurring later than the passed moment.
```

In Java with JDBC 4.2 or later:

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , secondsSinceEpoch ) ;  // Pass seconds calculated above.
```

Retrieval.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

## Count-from-epoch

Your number of type `long` is presumably a count of whole seconds or milliseconds since an [epoch reference date](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)).

If your chosen epoch happens to be that used by [“Unix time”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), the first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, then we can parse in Java as an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html). An `Instant` is a moment on the timeline in UTC with a resolution of nanoseconds. An `Instant` internally is a pair of numbers: a count of whole seconds since epoch, plus a fraction of a second as a count of nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( x ) ;
```

…or:

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond( x ) ;
```

## A day is *not* 24 hours

A day, as in a date on the calendar, is not the same thing as 24 hours. Anomalies in the way politicians define time zones such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) means a day might be 23, 23.5, 24, 25, or some other number of hours-minutes-seconds.

### `Duration`

If you want to add chunks of 24-hours, use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html).

```
Duration d = Duration.ofDays( 3 ) ;  // `Duration` defines a “day” as being a 24-hours without regard for the calendar dates.
```

Or specify in hours, which has the same result in `Duration` class but would be more clear as to your intent and understanding.

```
Duration d = Duration.ofHours( 3 * 24 ) ;  // Same effect as the `Duration.ofDays( 3 )` seen above.
```

Add to your `Instant`.

```
Instant instantLater = instant.plus( d ) ;
```

### `Period`

If you meant a day as incrementing a day on the calendar, use [`Period`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Period.html) class. This class represents a number of years-months-days.

```
Period p = Period.ofDays( 3 ) ;  // `Period` defines a day as a date on the calendar without regard for its length in hours.
```

We cannot add that to `Instant` without regard for time zone issues. If added to an `Instant` which is always in UTC we would be using the calendar of UTC. For example, adding a day to a value in UTC might translate to “tomorrow” in India while still being “yesterday” in Québec. A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone.

If no time zone is specified, the JVM implicitly applies its current default time zone. That default may [change at any moment](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html#getDefault()) during runtime(!), so your results may vary. Better to specify your [desired/expected time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) explicitly as an argument.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as `America/Montreal`, `Africa/Casablanca`, or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 2-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone, ask for it and pass as an argument. If omitted, the JVM’s current default is applied implicitly. Better to be explicit, as the default may be changed at any moment *during runtime* by any code in any thread of any app within the JVM.

Apply your `ZoneId` to the `Instant` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Now you can add days to the `ZonedDateTime` and the calendar used by the people of that region will be taken into account.

```
ZonedDateTime zdtLater = zdt.plus( p ) ;  // By “later” we assume the number of days in the `Period` is positive. Alternatively, a `Period` could go backwards in time with a negative number of days.
```

To adjust back to UTC, extract a `Instant`. We still have the same moment, the same point on the timeline, but with a different wall-clock time.

```
Instant instantLater = zdtLater.toInstant() ;  // Same moment, different wall-clock time.
```

The elapsed time between `zdt` and `zdtLater` may or may not be `( 3 * 24 )` hours. If a DST cutover occurred during that time, the number of hours would be either `( ( 3 * 24 ) - 1 )` in the “Spring Ahead” early in the year, or `( ( 3 * 24 ) + 1 )` in the “Fall Back” of the autumn.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).